# index on a float field seems to be ignored

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a `titles` table of about 14000 records, with a float field `average_rating`, which is indexed. But when I try to get the first 48 records with the highest `average_rating`, the index doesn't do any work. What am I doing wrong?

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM `titles` WHERE (average_rating is not null) \
ORDER BY average_rating desc LIMIT 0, 48\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: titles
         type: range
possible_keys: index_titles_on_average_rating
          key: index_titles_on_average_rating
      key_len: 5
          ref: NULL
         rows: 14114
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I'm far from a master of understanding explains, and I've never used MySql.  But isn't that saying that it *is* using the index?  If not, what does the line reading `key: index_titles_on_average_rating` mean?

Comment: @dan: what leads you to believe that the index is not being used?

Comment: It says mysql would read 14114 rows. Could this be right when I'm just asking for 48 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the Explain just is ignoring the LIMIT clause.